# Position: Absolute and Position: relative Problem in ie

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have a problem. See the code below please.

```
<div style="position:relative; overflow:hidden; width:120px;">
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0px;">Content</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:40px;">Content</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:80px;">Content</div>
</div>
```

The problem is, that in firefox, its working fine; but when i run this code in ie-8, it gives problem. All the divs with position:absolute are `40px` wide. they should just simply attain the position i assign them to. In ie, the 2nd div with `position:absolute` take double left-space. It counts the first div to be of `40px` and then counts `40px` more. It should just take `40px` from the relatively positioned div's left side. Can somebody help please?

Comment: Is that all the CSS for these divs? If you have a float:left; on the children divs it might be causing the problem you're describing

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected in ie7 & ie8. And drop that overflow: hidden, because it hides everything. Look here how it all looks with border: http://jsfiddle.net/uWkJ7/1/
All divs expand to their content width.

Comment: You can look at the [link]http://dev1.mybex.com/bhdarchitects/projects.php?subcat=4&prodid=1&imgid=8[/link]. Observe the two images in the gallery. the first hides behind the left arrow in firefox, while it shows fine in ie. when i give 40px from left, firefox show corrent result, but ie pushes it 40px forward and creates problems.

Comment: Well i solved this issue myself. I gave `left:0;` in the css and applied hack that applied only to ie. the hack is,
`html>/**/body left:40px;`

Comment: I investigated this issue. That is definitely some ie bug.

Answer (score 0):

In “non-layout” elements, hasLayout is not triggered, i.e. a pure div without a dimension can be a “non-layout ancestor”.